# Split Line by points with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm having some troubles trying to split a Linestring with 3 points.

My line is a circular route from a Garage (GA) to a pick up (PU) point, then a drop off (DO) point, and return to garage (img1)
[image]

And I'm trying to split this line by this three points, in order to get 3 lines (`Garage(GA)->PickUp (PU)`, `PU-DropOff(DO)`, `DO-GA`) First would be the left one, then the small one in the South, and finally the right one.

I'm using postgis `ST_LineSubstring and ST_LineLocatePoint`, but the result is not the expected, as I'm getting wrong return line:
[image]

I'm getting the `PU-DO` route (purple) as expected, and `DO-GA` as well (green) but for the fisrt segment (`GA-PU`) I'm not getting the one in the left, but I'm getting a new one behind the other (in blue)

[image]

I'm using the queries:

```sql
SELECT 1,ST_LineSubstring(geom, ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, PU),
 ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, DO)) 
FROM table;
SELECT 1,ST_LineSubstring(geom, ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, DO),
 ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, GA)) 
FROM table;
SELECT 1,ST_LineSubstring(geom, ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, GA),
 ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, PU)) 
FROM table;
```

And the results are the three lines shown.

Is there any way to get the other segment (the left one) in the third query instead of the one behind the others?

Comment: Will you please determine the point you would like to split the Garage-PU line?

Comment: The point would be the Pick Up point (in the South) to get the left segment.
Maybe this result is because is a closed line (circular)?

Comment: it isn't quite clear in your queries - ori (origin?) = Garage, dest (destination) = PU? then what is garage point in your second query... I am puzzled. You mentioned the order is Garage-PU, PU-DO, DO-GA. So, that is for the point: ST_LineSubstring(geom, ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, Garage) (= or ST_StartPoint(geom)), ST_LineLocatePoint(geom, PU)) and so on... If not so, please explain the ori and dest points

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the points. The route should be: GA->PU, then PU->DO,  and then DO->GA. So, my 3 queries are trying to split the line with each pair of locations.

Comment: Pablo Jane pointed out to you that the line on the left presented on your screenshot is not broken by any point, which means that in order to define the line on the left you need to use a different approach ... maybe you need to add two points in the nodes ...